# CSS Box Shadow - Not working on bottom

Tags: css, box-shadow

I'm using the following code and want the div class "certificate" to have a box shadow around the right and bottom. It only shows on the right - Any suggestions please on how I should amend this code? I've tried everything I could think of, any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    <?php
    get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    //create full width template
    kleo_switch_layout('full');
    ?>

    <?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-before-wrap'); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'page-parts/page-title' ); ?>
    <!-- <div class="main-content <?php echo Kleo::get_config('container_class'); ?>"> -->

    <!-- chelsea put your stuff below here -->
    <div class="certificate" style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px solid;padding: 10px; box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px grey; z-index: 10;">    
        <center><h1 style="font-family:verdana;" color="black"><b>Digital Badge Certificate</b></h1></center>
        <center><p style="margin-bottom:0;">Congratulations</p></center>
        <center><h2 style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;"><b><i>
                    <?php global $current_user;
                    wp_get_current_user();
                    echo $current_user->display_name
                    ?> </i></b></h2></center>
        <center><p style="margin-top:0;">You have earned the following badges:</p></center>

    <!-- test code for listing badge icons-->

         <?php
               if ( is_user_logged_in () ) {
                  $achievements = badgeos_get_user_achievements();

                        if ( !empty( $achievements ) ) {
                             foreach ( $achievements as $achievement ) {
                                echo '<div style="width:150px;height:150px;display:inline;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 10px" class="badge-list">';
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $achievement->ID, array(150,150) );
                                // echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $achievement->ID, 'thumbnail' );
                                echo '</div>';       
                                }
                            }

                                else {
                                _e( 'No achievements to display', 'text-domain' );
                                }
                 }
       ?>

</div><!-- end of certificate div -->
<!--cheslea put your stuff above here -->


<!-- Wordpress begins - don't put anything below here------------------- -->

  <?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-after-wrap'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Use a generator: http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/.  Also please post rendered html rather than php if it is a css problem - it helps with creating a [mcve]

Comment: Additionally `center` tags are obsolete and should not be used - use css instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center and the meaning of  `b` and `i` tags have changed - you probably want to use `strong` and `em` instead

Comment: Even if @Pete is right, your current basic HTML is working as you expect (meaning box-shadow is well rendered). Are you sure your `.certificate` div is not nested in another container which has a `overflow:hidden` for instance?